# Python - Add item to lists of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list "X":

```
X = ["'A':", [], "'B':", [], "'C':", [], "'D':", [], "'E':", []]
```

At indexes 1,3,5,7,... in my list I have another empty list.

How can I add some items to lists in list?

My list should be like:

```
X = ["'A':", [1,2], "'B':", [2,3,4], "'C':", [3,4,6], "'D':", [1,2], "'E':", [3]]
```

Comment: What's the logic?

Comment: your "list" looks like you want to use a `dict`, `{"A": [1,2], "B":[2, 3], ...}`

Comment: `X[1] = [1,2]` and so on

Comment: Feels like a http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @GaryvanderMerwe Maybe better link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem :-)

Comment: How did you get your "list" `X` in the first place? `"'A':"` indicates a problem earlier in your process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a rule, then please tell us.
If you want to give the additional items manually, then here is the example:

```
X[1].extend([1,2])
X[3].extend([2,3,4])
X[5].extend([3,4,6])
X[7].extend([1,2])
X[9].extend([3])
```

Comment: Thank You, this is what I needed.

Comment: @MyRandomUsername You are welcome. Could you please accept the answare?

Answer (score 1):

its pretty strightforward, you can simply do :

```
x[1].append(1)
x[1].append(2)
```

and so on to add items to the lists in that spot